# Use Jenkins CI for Qt projects

Tags: c++, qt, jenkins, qmake, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use Jenkins for some project I have written in Qt framework.

There is [qmake plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/qmakebuilder+Plugin) for Jenkins in Jenkins wiki page, although this plug-in doesn't exist in Jenkins plug-in list.

I've looked for .hpi file for qmakebuilder plug-in, couldn't find it though. So I download the source code from the given repository, tried to compile it as described in [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial)... but I get list of error indicating java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Any of you guys have used this plug-in? or any other Jenkins plug-in to compile Qt projects with?

Comment: Have you already set up job using the Windows bat file or the Unix shell script build step? What is that approach missing, that the plugin has?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by job, but I have installed Jenkins by adding the repository and using rpm (zypper since I'm using openSuse). Then I was looking for a qmake plug-in (either in their plug-in list to install through web UI or a the hpi file) which I couldnt find, so I tried to compile the source code of [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/qmakebuilder+Plugin) plugin to get the hpi file, but I faced some error. I have explained it in my answer.

Comment: By setting up a job I mean, after you have Jenkins running, go to Jenkins dashboard front page and click "new job", select freestyle, add shell script build step.

Comment: I see, well I was looking to use qmake by a plug-in rather than script, but sure you can install cmake and invoke qmake. cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, my `JAVA_HOME` variable was not pointing at the right folder i.e. JDK folder and it was set to JRE which caused the maven to not work properly.

But after fixing that, I was still getting some compilation error.

Finally, I [asked Jenkins people](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jenkinsci-users/Db_oZWtsQGk/discussion) and realized for some reason qmakebuilder is not compatible with JDK 7. Therefore, I download the JDK 6 compile the code with that version and it got compiled just fine. I got the hpi file in the target folder.

Plus, the hpi file for this plug-in NOW can be find [here.](https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/plugins/job/qmakebuilder-plugin/1/hudson.plugins.qmake%24qmakebuilder/)